# How do I name the output textfile to YYYYMMDD based on the system date?

Tags: sqlcmd

How do I name the output textfile to YYYYMMDD based on the system date?

```
sqlcmd -S DataBBB -i c:\scripts\followup.sql
    -o %DATE:~4,2%_%DATE:~7,2%_%DATE:~-4%.txt -s ; -W -u
```

Now the output text file is `01_31_2012.txt`.
How can I change it to `2012_01_31.txt`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tried it under Windows 7 Premium (German), may be dependent upon OS and Local Time Format.

```
sqlcmd -S DataBBB -i c:\scripts\followup.sql 
                            -o %date:~-4%_%date:~3,2%_%date:~0,2%.txt -s;
```

You have to edit this part for your system

```
%date:~-4%_%date:~3,2%_%date:~0,2%.txt
```

The statement used the command line internal `%date%` - variable with the extension `:~start,length`. So you can create the filename with different parts from the `date`- variable.

Comment: Completely unrelated: "addicted" is really for drugs and similar: _I am addicted to Stack Overflow._

Comment: I came across similar issue so thought will copy the solution on this thread as well: -o %DATE:~-4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%.txt