# Sqlcmd .bat file sql output with date append

Tags: batch-file, sql-server-2012, sqlcmd

I have a .bat file that I have scheduled to run daily at 1am using task scheduler on a *windows server 2008 r2*. The final output file gets overwritten every time so I need to add a date after the output file name.

Here is the `code` in `.bat` file :

```
SQLCMD -S ServerName -d DbName-E -i C:\loc\script.sql -o C:\loc\scriptOutputtemp.txt -s"|" -W
findstr /B /V /C:"----" "C:\loc\scriptOutputtemp.txt" > "C:\loc\finaloutput.txt"
del "C:\loc\scriptOutputtemp.txt"
```

I tried to add `%date%` like `"C:\loc\finaloutput%date%.txt"` but then nothing gets generated as output. It's my first time creating this so any guidance will be helpful.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get current datetime on the Windows command line, in a suitable format for using in a filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-do-i-get-current-datetime-on-the-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format)

Comment: Solution in this thread worked! :) Someone please mark this as an answer. Thank you!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074407/how-do-i-name-the-output-textfile-to-yyyymmdd-based-on-the-system-date

Comment: Delete your question then as you can see it is a duplicate.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. This thread will help other users since it has additional information where the code is deleting "----".

Comment: You want me to show you all the questions that address the issue with the SQLCMD outputing that dashed line underneath the header.

Comment: Show me the exact similar logic on any other thread please then I will delete mine.

Comment: Here is the final solution that I was really looking for that I couldn't exactly find anywhere!!!! "C:\loc\finaloutput%DATE:~-4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%.txt"

Comment: Perhaps [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22103637), addresses the dashed line issue!